# searching data in a database

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2008, search

Here is the aspx.cs file for my web application:

> protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>       {

```
    SqlDataReader myDataReader = null;
    string connectionString = "Data Source=[my source];Initial Catalog=[catalog name];Integrated Security=True";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {

        SqlCommand returnResults = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + categoryName + " FROM Teacher WHERE " + categoryName + " LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'", connection);

        connection.Open();
      myDataReader = returnResults.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        while (myDataReader.Read())
        {
            Console.Write(myDataReader.GetInt32(0) + "\t");
            Console.Write(myDataReader.GetString(2) + " " + myDataReader.GetString(1) + "\t");
            Console.Write(myDataReader.GetString(3) + "\t");
            if (myDataReader.IsDBNull(4))
                Console.Write("N/A\n");
            else
                Console.Write(myDataReader.GetInt32(4) + "\n");
        }


        myDataReader.Close();
        connection.Close();

    }


}

   protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    categoryName = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;

}
protected void SearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    searchText = SearchBox.Text;
}
```

My database has a table with around 24 columns. The DropDownList I have created has an option to select each of these column names. There is a SearchBox underneath where the user can enter a keyword to search.

I want to save the DropDownList selection as "categoryName," and I want to save the SearchBox input as "searchText". When I run the application, I get this error:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
>
> Source Error:
>    Line 48: myDataReader=returnResults.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

I'm not sure how to progress from here, so any help is appreciated. If you need more info please ask.

Comment: Fosco has given a valid answer for your question, however you should really use a parameterized SQL statement to protect against SQL injection attacks.  See SO questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664314/c-constructing-paramater-query-sql-like

Comment: Throw a breakpoint in there, and double-check the actual query that is being constructed. Does it work when you copy the query into another medium? Although I'm betting on the spaces issue pointed out in another answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
SqlCommand returnResults = new SqlCommand("SELECT categoryName FROM Teacher WHERE categoryName LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'", connection);
```

This is assuming categoryName is the column you want in return, and also the one you want searched.  Your original query was doing a few things wrong: using a variable instead of the column name, and the LIKE value wasn't quoted.

If the column to be searched is dynamic, and selected by the drop down box, and the value is stored in the variable categoryName:

```
SqlCommand returnResults = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + categoryName + " FROM Teacher WHERE " + categoryName + " LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'", connection);
```

Comment: I ran your code and I got this error:

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'categoryName'.
Invalid column name 'categoryName'.

That made me think that my values are being stored incorrectly. Sure enough, their values were null. This is the code I have to store a value:

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        categoryName = e.ToString();
        
    }

What should be the proper code to record the dropdown list selection as a string?

Thanks for all your help. I'm just starting so it's all new.

Comment: In the database, what is the column name you are trying to search?  Is it really user-selectable?

Comment: I added another query if the column name is a user selection, but you may need to provide more info on the table structure.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I updated the first post to reflect the info you asked for, but it's basically a standard table with around 24 columns.

Comment: The Value of the dropdown box that you place in the variable categoryName.. is that the COLUMN name in the table structure?  The second query should work for you, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, the value of the dropdown is indeed the column name in the table structure. I tried your second query but I still get the error that I described in the bottom of my post.

Comment: You will need to place a breakpoint at the line of the query and look at the string it is building.  I suspect if it is complaining about 'FROM' that the categoryName variable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be missing blank spaces

`"SELECT" + categoryName + "FROM Teacher WHERE" + searchText + " LIKE " + "%" +  searchText + "%", connection);`

is going to return something like

`SELECTmycolumnnameFROM Teacher WHEREmycolumn LIKE %john%`

I think you should do this

`"SELECT " + categoryName + " FROM Teacher WHERE " + searchText + " LIKE """ + "%" +  searchText + "%""", connection);`

to get

`SELECT mycolumnname FROM Teacher WHERE mycolumn LIKE "%john%"`

Comment: The triple '"""' gave an error, but I followed Fosco's code and cleaned it up. Thanks!