# How do I execute a MySQL parameterized query in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, mysql, parameters

When I run this command in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM v
WHERE v.firstname LIKE '%a%' OR middlename LIKE '%a%' OR lastname LIKE '%a%'
```

It returns 4 rows in the result set.

But when I run the same query using parameters in C# it returns only one.

```
SELECT * FROM v
WHERE v.firstname  LIKE ?word OR middlename LIKE ?word OR lastname 

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("word", '%'+key+'%');
```

I also tried `'%' ?word '%'` and adding the parameter (key) only, but this didn't work either.

How do I make this work?

Comment: How do you run your DbCommand? Show us the next statement after AddWithValue.

Comment: Did you try running the query hardcoded in your C# code?

Comment: don't worry it's work the problem is not in query elsewhere. the codewar tag i make for testing that how it's work.if anyone have problem destroy them i have no objection on them.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664314/c-constructing-paramater-query-sql-like) seems to have addressed the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using something like:

```
cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

in your code? It will return only 1 record. Try

```
cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing "LIKE ?word" at then end of your second SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE v.firstname  LIKE ?word OR middlename LIKE ?word OR lastname 
are you missing lastname LIKE ?word ?