# Add parameter issue for fulltext search in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have this part of code

```
string query = "SELECT ID, COL1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE CONTAINS(COL1,@text)";

sqlCommand.CommandText = sql;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@text", value+"*");
```

`value` is a function parameter.

For fulltext search, the sql statement must be like this:

```
SELECT ID, COL1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE CONTAINS(COL1,'"eng*"')
```

It could search strings which start with "eng" -> english, bla blah.

But executing in C# the above code then `ExecuteReader()` returns empty list.

@text has as value `"sometext*"` but I want to add `' '` characters.

I tried `string query = "SELECT ID, COL1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE CONTAINS(COL1,'@text')";`
but it doesn't work, returns empty list.

Why ? How do I proceed that `@text` parameters must include `''` characters over value for search ?

Thank you

Comment: If you read your own question as if you hadn't wrote it, do you understand it? I am thinking about for example *"It could search strings which start with "eng" -> english, bla blah."* - It is not clear what you mean here. *"@text has as value "value*" but I want to add ' ' characters."* - What should be the end result of this, `value* `? or perhaps `value*' '`? *"but it doesn't work !"*, why does it not work? error messages? does it crash? what happends? *"How do I proceed that @text must include '' characters over value for search ?"* So text should be `value*''`? Please try to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using `sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", value+"*");`

If above doesn't work, you can use [SQL Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) and [SqlDBType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.sqldbtype.aspx).

I think your SQL query is wrong. See is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664314/c-sharp-constructing-parameter-query-sql-like) post helps.

[C# constructing parameter query SQL - LIKE %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664314/c-sharp-constructing-parameter-query-sql-like)

Comment: I don't want LIKE...I will use CONTAINS for fulltext search because it is faster method for my project !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the data type? I don't think you should need the quotes in the sqlcommand string.

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@text", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCommand.Parameters["@text"].Value = value+"*";
```

Or SqlDbType.NVarChar.

Comment: * is for fulltext search when you use CONTAINS keyword