# How to use parameters "@" in an SQL command in VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, parameters

I have this code to update my SQL database from data in a textbox, in VB. I need to use parameters in case the text contains a tic mark ,', or a quote ,", etc. Here is what I have:

```
dbConn = New SqlConnection("server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI; database=FATP")
    dbConn.Open()

    MyCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE SeansMessage SET Message = '" & TicBoxText.Text & _
                                            "'WHERE Number = 1", dbConn)

    MyDataReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader()
    MyDataReader.Close()
    dbConn.Close()
```

And this is my lame attempt to set a parameter from what I have seen on the web, which I don't understand all that well.

```
dbConn = New SqlConnection("server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI; database=FATP")
    dbConn.Open()

    MyCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE SeansMessage SET Message = @'" & TicBoxText.Text & _
                                            "'WHERE Number = 1", dbConn)

    MyDataReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader()
    MyDataReader.Close()
    dbConn.Close()
```

How do you do this? Cause if there is a ' mark in the textbox when I run the code, it crashes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# constructing parameter query SQL - LIKE %](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664314/c-sharp-constructing-parameter-query-sql-like)

Comment: [Also see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx#Y300)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are on the right path to avoiding [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/), but your understanding of `@` parameters is incomplete.

Named parameters behave like *variables* in a programming language: first, you use them in your SQL command, and then you supply their value in your VB.NET or C# program, like this:

```
MyCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE SeansMessage SET Message = @TicBoxText WHERE Number = 1", dbConn)
MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TicBoxText", TicBoxText.Text)
```

Note how the text of your command became self-contained: it no longer depends on the value of the text from the text box, so the users cannot break your SQL by inserting their own command. `@TicBoxText` became a name of the variable that stands for the value in the text of the command; the call to `AddWithValue` supplies the value. After that, your `ExecuteReader` is ready to go.

Comment: Not a fan of the AddWithValue() method. Sometimes it guesses the parameter type wrong (ie: dates, varchar vs nvarchar), and sometimes when that happens the query no longer lines up with an index that it should, resulting in sometimes drastic performance problems.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Me neither, but that's the fastest way to get things going.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense for my purposes.

Answer (score 12):

There are a number of improvements in here:

```vb
Using dbConn As New SqlConnection("server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI; database=FATP"), _
      MyCommand As SqlCommand("UPDATE SeansMessage SET Message = @Message WHERE Number = 1", dbConn)

    'Make sure to use your exact DbType (ie: VarChar vs NVarChar) and size
    MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@Message", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TicBoxText.Text

    dbConn.Open()
    MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() ' don't open a data reader: just use ExecuteNonQuery
End Using 'Using block will close the connection for you
```

Comment: What are these improvements of which there are a number?

Comment: @PsychoData Correctly close the connection in case an exception is thrown, use query parameters, executenonquery() instead of executereader, explicit parameter type instead of inferred