# How to use not operator in SQL using vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net-2010

My problem now is about how to use "not equal" in SQL. Here is my code:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    With cmd
        .CommandText = "SELECT [Position],[Partylist],[Fullname],[Lvl],[Votes] FROM tbl_cands WHERE [Department] = '" & elem & "'AND [PositionID]=" & pres & ""
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandTimeout = 30
        .Connection = conn
    End With
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
```

I need not to display fullname that is not equivalent to None.

Comment: This code looks like it could open you to SQL injection hacks. Consider using parameterized techniques instead.

Comment: Do you mean just adding `AND [Fullname] <> 'None'` to your query?

Comment: yes,  @Szymon exactly

Comment: I've posted it as the answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are checking for NULL then the code is:

```
AND [Fullname] IS NOT NULL
```

If you want to check the value isn't a zero length string:

```
AND [Fullname] <> ''
```

If you want to check it isn't a specific value that denotes no data:

```
AND [Fullname] <> 'None'
```

But in any case, I strongly recommend you read the following link and learn how to use parameterization for your SqlCommand object. If you don't escape strings correctly you leave yourself vulnerable to injection hacks:

[How to use parameters "@" in an SQL command in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139791/how-to-use-parameters-in-an-sql-command-in-vb)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to add that to your query:

```
AND [Fullname] <> 'None'
```