# Can you pass more than 1 parameter in a single SQL statement through a VB command?

Tags: sql, vb.net

Just wondering can you pass 2 parameters ( @Insertparanamehere ) in 1 sql command via VB? I have some code below ( sample code ) and I am just wondering is this possible.

```
Command = New SqlCommand("Update Boards Set CDF_Supplier_Tx='" + SupplierNameTxt.Text + "'  Where CDF_Supplier_tx IN ( Select Supplier From Suppliers Where Supplier = '" + SupplierNameTxt.Text + "')", connection)
```

Where it says `'" + SupplierNameTxt.Text + "'`  could this be potentially replaced with `@Insertnameparaname` from here?

If this is unclear as to which I will try to explain this a little more so my code would end up with 2x@ instead of the long supplierNameTxt.Text?

This is just a question , thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd be careful if I were you, you are very vulnerable on SQL injections attacks with such a design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MyCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE SeansMessage SET Message1 = @TicBoxText1, Message2 = @TicBoxText2 WHERE Number = 1", dbConn)`
`MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TicBoxText1", TicBoxText1.Text)`
`MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TicBoxText2", TicBoxText2.Text)`

See here:

[How to use parameters "@" in an SQL command in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139791/how-to-use-parameters-in-an-sql-command-in-vb)

You can also use the same parameter multiple times in your SQL text.

Comment: Why thank you , this help me answer my question at hand! Voted Answer.

Comment: No worries. I'd recommend however you consider using entity framework, as opposed to directly using SQL unless you have certain specific requirements