# Incorrect Syntax Near "("

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, syntax, sql-update

So I was trying to do Update my database using buttons in VB.Net. I tried following different syntax in Updating tables but it still come up with the same error. It is so frustrating because we are running out of time to finish our system because of this. Please help me :'(

So this is my code wherein it will called after the button is clicked. What is wrong with my syntax here?

```
Public Sub UpdateClient(Client_ID As Integer, _ClientName As String, _Company_Add As String, _Email_Add As String,
                    _Tin_No As String, _Contact_Person As String, _Mobile_No As String, _Telephone_No As String,
                    _Remarks As String, _User As String)

    Try
        Dim strInsert As String = "UPDATE CLIENTS SET (ClientID = '" & Client_ID & "', ClientName = '" & _ClientName & "', Company_Add = '" & _Company_Add & "', Email_Add = '" & _Email_Add & "', Tin_No = '" & _Tin_No & "', Contact_Person = '" & _Contact_Person & "', Mobile_No = '" & _Mobile_No & "', Telephone_No = '" & _Telephone_No & "', Remarks = '" & _Remarks & "', User_ = '" & _User & "') WHERE (ClientID = '" & Client_ID & "') "

        SQLCon.Open()
        SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(strInsert, SQLCon)
        SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        SQLCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

Then here is my code on the button event:

```
Public Sub Update_Client()

    SQL.UpdateClient(ClientIDLabel1.Text, txtCnamee.Text, txtCadd.Text, txtEadd.Text, txtTin.Text, txtCper.Text, txtMno.Text, txtTel.Text, txtRem.Text, User_Label1.Text)



End Sub
```

I'm pretty sure the error is in my sql string. What could it be? Please please help me :'(

P.s. I'm new to using VB.Net. Please bear with me :( Thank you.

Comment: There is no open paren after the `SET`.

Comment: Use SQL Parameters.  If you have a client named O'Brian or D'Angelo you app will crash

Comment: @Plutonix OMG THANK THANK YOU SO MUCH :')

Comment: It's worse than that. If someone tried to update their name to [`Robert');DROP Table Clients;--`](https://xkcd.com/327/)  you'd be in real trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the immediate problem with your code: the syntax of `UPDATE` is as follows:

```
UPDATE <table> SET <field1>=<value1>, <field2>=<value2> ...
```

Note that the list of variables that you set is *not* enclosed in parentheses. You need to remove `(` and `)` from your parenthesized list to fix the syntax problem in your SQL:

```
Dim strInsert As String = "UPDATE CLIENTS SET ClientID = '" & Client_ID & "', ClientName = '" & _ClientName & "', Company_Add = '" & _Company_Add & "', Email_Add = '" & _Email_Add & "', Tin_No = '" & _Tin_No & "', Contact_Person = '" & _Contact_Person & "', Mobile_No = '" & _Mobile_No & "', Telephone_No = '" & _Telephone_No & "', Remarks = '" & _Remarks & "', User_ = '" & _User & "' WHERE (ClientID = '" & Client_ID & "') "
```

However, there is a much bigger problem: your program can be broken by =SQL injection attacks, which is very dangerous. You need to rewrite your SQL to accept parameters, and use parameterized SQL to fix this vulnerability. See [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11139935/335858) for a quick example of how to parameterize your query.

Comment: Descent answer, but would suggest showing sample of parameterizing the query with their instance vs just stating it.  Great point about SQL-Injection