# How can I fix the vb.net error "array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers"?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, insert, sqlcommand

How can I fix the vb.net error "array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers" in the following code?

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=WebAssignment1;Integrated Security=True")
con.Open()
Dim command As SqlCommand ("Insert into List_Assignment values ('"& tid &"','"& task &"','"& customer &"','"& mandays &"','"& startDate &"','"& addDate &"','"& estimateDate &"','"& status &"','"& completionDate &"','"& remark &"','"& lastUpdate &"')", con)
Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
MessageBox.Show("Successfully Insert.")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cdCJ.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```vb
Dim command As SqlCommand (...)
```

instead of

```vb
Dim command As New SqlCommand (...)
```

therefore, the VB compiler thinks that `SqlCommand (x, y, z ..)` is an array type. When you add the `New` keyword, VB knows that you are calling  a constructor with arguments.

---

If you convert the string expression to string interpolation, the statement becomes more readable

```vb
Dim command As New SqlCommand($"Insert into List_Assignment values ('{tid}','{Task}','{customer}','{mandays}','{startDate}','{addDate}','{estimateDate}','{status}','{completionDate}','{remark}','{lastUpdate}')", con)
```

But this is problematic anyway, because possible [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Another problem is that you are obviously inserting everything as text (because of the single quotes). Either all the columns are really text columns, then your database design is bad, because dates and number must be typed as such, or some columns are not text columns and your insert command is wrong.

See also: [How to use parameters "@" in an SQL command in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11139791/880990)

Answer (score 0):

Well, too bad you did not post the code as text - I would have cut + pasted more working code.

But, your code should be setup something like this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim status As String
    If RadioAktif.Checked = True Then
        status = "Aktif"
    Else
        status = "Non Aktif"
    End If

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "INSERT ListAssigmment (id, task, customer, mandays, Status)
        VALUES (@id, @task, @customer, @mandays, @Status)"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0 ' textCustID.Text
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@task", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextTask.Text
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@customer", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextCustomer.Text
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@mandays", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextManDays.Text
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =  Status

            conn.Open()
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using
    End Using
```

Above is air code, since I can't re-type all of your code in a picture - that would cause world poverty  and take too much time.

However, the above code is "close" and a good working example of how you should and want to approach this.

So, as a general rule, in the SQL, you want to specify BOTH the columns, and then the values to insert.