# Wild Card % Giving an Error in a SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, wildcard

This Oracle SQL query written in c# is  giving me  the following error : *invalid character*

```
qur = " select * from emp where name LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'";
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: please do parameterized the query. what if i set the value of my textbox with `'; DROP emp; --`

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be on `%` character. What does `TextBox1.Text` contain?

Comment: I enter a name, with  some  characters

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your query is very open to Sql Injection attacks. Since you are not using parametrized queries anything entered in TextBox1 can crush your query.

for example if I enter : ' char in Textbox your query will be `select * from emp where name LIKE '%'%'` and it will  throw error. And apart from that it is vulnerability and you should not use such queries.

You can change query to  :

```
SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand( " select * from emp where name LIKE @myParam");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myParam", "%" + TextBox1.Text + "%");
```

you missed `@`

[How do parameterized queries help against SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection)

[C# constructing parameter query SQL - LIKE %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664314/c-sharp-constructing-parameter-query-sql-like)

Comment: @SandraDsouza you are welcome. Just be careful about Sql Injection attacks. It is a very  serious problem.

Answer (score -2):

you should use it as below:

```
qur = " select * from emp where name LIKE '%'" + TextBox1.Text + "'%'";
```