# Formatting LIKE in odbc_prepare

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute the following PHP code but am getting 0 rows in return even though there is a matching row when executed in command line:

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Coupons] WHERE [code] LIKE '%?%' AND [platform] LIKE '%?%'";
$stmt = odbc_prepare($link, $sql);
odbc_execute($stmt, array($coupon,$platform));
```

How do I properly format the LIKE's in the query?

I tried

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Coupons] WHERE [code] LIKE ? AND [platform] LIKE ?"
```

but that doesn't work either.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this post out:

[C# constructing parameter query SQL - LIKE %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664314/c-sharp-constructing-parameter-query-sql-like)

You need to pass in the entire string, `'%value%'` as the parameter so in your case

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Coupons] WHERE [code] LIKE ? AND [platform] LIKE ?";
$stmt = odbc_prepare($link, $sql);
odbc_execute($stmt,array("%{$coupon}%","%{$platform}%"));
```

Comment: Thanks!
$sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Coupons] WHERE [code] LIKE ? AND [platform] LIKE ?";
$stmt = odbc_prepare($link, $sql);
odbc_execute($stmt, array("%".$coupon."%","%".$platform."%"));

Comment: Sorry I have never coded in PHP, but from what I read you can use that syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string . If it doesn't work, you can concatenate the strings however you want. Did the solution work for you?