# Displaying data from my database based on what the user is typing

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I am trying to display data from my database based on what the user is typing.

Why doesn't the query return any results even though I'm sure I have at least one matching result?

Here's what I have right now.

```
private void txbSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// The query is on several lines for greater readability.
    string query = @"
        SELECT titre_fr, titre_en 
        FROM tfilms 
        WHERE titre_fr  LIKE '%@text%' 
        OR titre_en LIKE '%@text2%'";
    if (txbSearch.Text != "")
    {
        using (var databaseConn = new MySqlConnection(conn))
        {
            using (var cmd = databaseConn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", txbSearch.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("%@text2", txbSearch.Text);
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                using (var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(dataTable);
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                    databaseConn.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                             // DO SOMRTHING
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        // IT ALWAYS LAND HERE.
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
        RefreshData();
}
```

Thank you in advance!

For example:
In my database, so far I have around 60 movies.  If i'm typing ninja, I want all the movies that contain the word ninja.  That should be giving me 3 results.

UPDATE:

I found out where my problem was.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("%@text2", txbSearch.Text);
```

t was the % in front of @text2. I also made the following changes.

```
cmd.Parameters".AddWithValue("@text", "%" + txbSearch.Text + "%");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text2", "%" + txbSearch.Text + "%");
```

instead of:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", txbSearch.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("%@text2", txbSearch.Text);
```

And I removed the '%%' in the query.  I don't know if it's ok, but it works.

Comment: Why are you quoting your parameters, such as `'%@text%'`? Parameters shouldn't be quoted. I'd expect you to get an exception with such a command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664314/c-sharp-constructing-parameter-query-sql-like

Comment: @gunr2171 Because it gives me an error if I don't do that.